# print hash keys and values if they are matched

Tags: perl, hash, matching, fuzzy-search

I am trying to match a hash to file.  However, what I am searching for and the file are not an exact match due to punctuation and spaces.  For example, I might have "JE Industries, Incorporated" in my hash and "JE Industries Incorporated" in my file.  Those two will obviously not match because of the ",", comma.

So my solution is to have a hash, and a file and perform modifications on each one (replace punctuation in both file and hash values so 'JE Industries, Incorporated' will match 'JE Industries Incorporated', along with other sets of rules.)  As soon as the match is satisfied, go to the next item in the hash against the file.  If that that match is not satisfied, go to next rule "elsif", and try to match that, if it is satisfied, go to next item etc. I would also like to have an unmodified copy of the hash and line so that the original of each is not modified.  So basically only one rule is applied at a time.

So I have been working on how to figure this out but my results are not what I want.

**CODE**

```
 open(my $fh, "list.txt");

    while(<$fh>) {
     my($line) = $_;
     chomp($line);
    my %hash = (
        12345 => 'JE Industries, Incorporated',
        123355 => 'Josh Industries, Inc'
    );
    while( my( $key, $value ) = each %hash ) {
    if($value =~ s/[[:punct:]]//gi eq $line =~ s/[[:punct:]]//gi) {print $line,",",$key,"\n";} #replace punctuation on both $line and $value to make them match##
    elsif($value =~ s/[\s]//gi eq $line =~ s/[\s]//gi) {print $value,",",$key,"\n";} ## if punctuation does not do it replace space##

}
}
```

**My file, list.txt**

JE Industries Incorporated
Josh Industries Inc
Jim bob & co.

**My output**

JE Industries Incorporated,123355
Josh Industries Inc,123355

**Desired output**

JE Industries Incorporated,"JE Industries, Incorporated",12345
Josh Industries Inc,"Josh Industries, Inc",123355

original_Value_from_file,"original_Value_from_hash",corresponding keys to each

It is matching my items from hash to file, however, it is only assigning each value the last key from the hash.  Also, I am a little unsure how to print the original form of each line/hash along with the match results.  Also keep in mind, for the modifications, I want to modify them from the start for each rule.  In other words, where the second rule happens, "$value =~ s/[\s]//gi eq $line =~ s/[\s]//gi", I want to replace \s in "JE Industries, Incorporated" not in "JE Industries Incorporated."

In the end I would like my result to be the original form of the match from the hash value, the original form of the $line value, and they corresponding hash key.  I will also be wanting to implement even more rules than just omitting punctuation and space to make a closer match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of time it is easier to prep your data ahead of time.
To make your code simpler later.

Here is what I would do create a reverse hash of non-punctuation names to the id.

When looping the file I just have to have to compare against my non-punctuation to id hash to find a match.

Working example below

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %id_to_name = (
    12345  => 'JE Industries, Incorporated',
    123355 => 'Josh Industries, Inc'
);
#Create a reverse map with out any punctuation
my %no_punc_name_to_id;
while (my ($key, $value) = each %id_to_name) {
    $value =~ s/[[:punct:]]//gi;
    $no_punc_name_to_id{$value} = $key;
}
my $filename = 'list.txt';
open my $fh , '<' , $filename or die "Cannot read '$filename': $!";

while(my $line = <$fh>)  {
    chomp($line);
    $line =~ s/[[:punct:]]//gi;
    if(exists $no_punc_name_to_id{$line}) {
        my $id = $no_punc_name_to_id{$line};
        print $line,",","\"$id_to_name{$id}\"",",",$id,"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: this gave me a great idea to assign my values into a temp hash and modify that one while still returning the original. @rouzier

Comment: Some general hints, please use `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. And use the three argument version of open with lexical filehandles and proper error handling `open my $filehandle , '<' , $filename or die "Cannot read '$filename': $!";`

Comment: Furthermore the `while` can be written more compact `while( my $line = <$fh>) {`.

Comment: @rouzier what if this hash is opened from a file handle instead of in the code?

Comment: @JDE876 Can you be more specific? 
What is the format of this file?